# JSON-RPC in Spring framework 3

Tags: java, javascript, spring, json-rpc

I need some recomendations, best practice/libs, when implementing JSON-RPC in my Spring 3 web application.

I found this http://code.google.com/p/jsonrpc4j/ but it didn't seem to be any relases available.

Edit:

For clarification, I want to provide a JSON-RPC service

Comment: I think you need to clarify. Do you intend to provide a Restful service or consume it?

Comment: jsonrpc4j project seems to have both [release](http://jsonrpc4j.googlecode.com/svn/maven/repo/com/googlecode/jsonrpc4j/0.23/) and [snapshot](http://jsonrpc4j.googlecode.com/svn/maven/repo/com/googlecode/jsonrpc4j/0.24-SNAPSHOT/) versions in the googlecode maven repository

Comment: Its based on Jackson which is stable and tested, I am guessing its a fairly thin wrapper over jackson as it does a lot out of the box. I may suggest using raw jackson yourself that way you get more control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) with **Jackson** can provide a **json** response with a **REST** call. This is easy. But I don't think there is any facility in native **Spring** to accept a [JSON-RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC#Version_1.1_.28Working_Draft.29) request including a method name and return a response including the **JSON-RPC** error codes.

Your best bet may be to look at a library like [jsonrpc4j](https://github.com/briandilley/jsonrpc4j).