# Is there any good JSON-RPC 1.0 compatible client library in java?

Tags: java, json-rpc

I'm working with the **Zcash RPC API's**. Essentially they are based on JSON-RPC 1.0 specification. I need to make those RPC calls using a java code. I've been searching for a good JSON-RPC 1.0 compatible library but couldn't find one.

Has anyone know about any such library, or can you suggest the alternative?

Answer (score -3):

You can use jsonrpc4j(https://github.com/briandilley/jsonrpc4j) if it helps. It also provides integration with spring.

Alternatively, you can see this answer [JSON-RPC in Spring framework 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883302/json-rpc-in-spring-framework-3).

Comment: I'm already using the same but they are based on JSON RPC 2.0 Specification however Zcash RPC supports only JSON RPC 1.0 Specification

Comment: Hah! Here 1½ later after I'm also looking for a JSON-RPC 1.0 library because Ripple RPC is also too old for school #NeverSendABankerToDoAProgrammersJob